# Are staking rewards that are calculated every epoch visible somewhere as transactions? if not - how can we compute such transactions?

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to calculate na IRR (internal rate of return) of all my staking operations, and for this I need all staking deposits, withdrawals, as well as all rewards calculated and awarded by validators at every epoch.

Deposits and withdrawals from the staking contract are easy to find, but I have absolutely no idea where/how to find the rewards.

Can someone put me on the right track? I'm expecting a transaction executed at the end of every epoch or something similar.

UPDATE: The most detailed description of the mechanics that I'm interested in seems to be on the staking-pool contract itself:

https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/staking-pool

And my understanding is that I could simply track my staked balance per validator from one transaction to another (the internal_ping function seems to be called all the time to distribute rewards).

So here goes the updated question:

What is the methodology of obtaining a time series of 'staking reward cash flows' - shall I simply look up the state of my staked balance on each of the validators that I delegated to for every epoch that I'm interested in, and 'piece together' the flows from the change in the staked balance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated [here](https://github.com/near/bounties/issues/41#issuecomment-778124082) you need to "go over each epoch and query the delegated balance for the given account from the staking pool(s), and display the difference between the value from a previous epoch".

You can query the delegated balance for an earlier block using javascript like this:

```
fetch('https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'jsonrpc': '2.0',
            'id': 'dontcare',
            'method': 'query',
            'params': {
                request_type: 'call_function',
                block_id: block_id,
                account_id: 'VALIDATOR_ACCOUNT.poolv1.near',
                method_name: 'get_account_total_balance',
                args_base64: btoa(JSON.stringify({
                    account_id: 'YOUR_ACCOUNT.near'
                }))
            }
        })
    })
```